# Как использовать элементы Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, toolbar

Поставил Toolbar и сделал кнопку "Назад". Не знаю как поставить на нее обработчик.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
if (toolbar != null) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: @user2070212 Вы ж уже задавали такой вопрос 3 часа тому назад.

Comment: @Lucky_girl там был другой вопрос, потом был отредактирован. Надо порядок навести, да.

Comment: задайте вопрос еще раз, Вам ответят, как только вы создадите 99 одинаковых вопросов.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Кнопку home нажали
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```